# Image tagging like facebook in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, photo-tagging

I am using asp.net and C#.

I have a image control, I want that people can tag that image[similar to facebook]. As I want to save the tag cordinated into the datbase, so that the admin can see the tags made by the user on the image. Please let me know how can I achieve this in asp.net with JQuery.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You ask for a full project that makes magics - and with out specified them.

Comment: Just a thought too can help me to think in a right direction.

Comment: do you mean tagging as in drawing a box around an area of the photo and tagging that, or just tagging the picture as a whole?

Comment: Image is a word wrap game, I want user to box[tag] the word they found in that image.

Comment: It could be like this too that user tag the pic then take a snap shot of that pic and submit that image to the admin. Is it possible to tag the pic and then take the snapshot of it ???

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Its possible to create facebook like tagging in asp.net

See the examples [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Facebook_Style_Photo_Tag.aspx)

and [here](http://www.facebooksdk.blogspot.com/)