# Adding tagging functionalities to photos in my website

Tags: asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Image tagging like facebook in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307881/image-tagging-like-facebook-in-asp-net)

I am developing a website. I want to add a functionality like tagging photos like we have in facebook and orkut.
please suggest how can i do that?

Is there any open source gallery(or paid) which i can directly plug in.

Any solution is welcomed as soon as possible.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://www.facebooksdk.blogspot.com/) and [Facebook style Photo Tag](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Facebook_Style_Photo_Tag.aspx) found in similar question in [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307881/image-tagging-like-facebook-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. [Face.com](http://face.com/) already provides an API for this functionality.

Take a look at [this website](http://www.ginktage.com/2011/08/using-face-api-in-c/) for information on a C# Wrapper.

Comment: Can i use those API in asp.net

Comment: Take a look at [this website](http://www.ginktage.com/2011/08/using-face-api-in-c/) for information on a C# Wrapper.